# Is it feasible to use decorator pattern with QWidget?

Tags: qt, design-patterns

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), I need to

> In the Decorator class, redirect all "Component" methods to the
>   "Component" pointer;

But `QWidget` has too many methods to redirect.
For example I want to create a moveable widget decorator:

```
class Moveable : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Moveable(QWidget * widgetToBeDecorated){
        this->widgetToBeDecorated = widgetToBeDecorated;
    }
    ~Moveable();

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* e) override {
        lastPoint = e->pos();
        widgetToBeDecorated->mousePressEvent(e);
    }
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* e) override {
        auto offset = e->pos()-lastPoint;
        lastPoint = e->pos();

        widgetToBeDecorated->move(widgetToBeDecorated->pos()+offset);
        widgetToBeDecorated->mouseMoveEvent(e);
    }
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* e) override {
        widgetToBeDecorated->mouseReleaseEvent(e);
    }

private:
    QWidget* widgetToBeDecorated;
    QPoint lastPoint;
};
```

Do I need to redirect other methods like `show()`, `paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)`?

Comment: "redirect all "Component” methods” - a “proper” decorator forwarding *all* calls is usually not possible with many of the Qt classes, because there are no purely abstract protocol classes/interfaces for things like widgets, QIODevices, and the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decorator pattern is a guideline, not a rule. You are fully allowed to modify patterns that do not suit your purposes. In this case, you only need to concern yourself with the part of `QWidget` that are involved with positioning, so there is no advantage to overriding any other of it's methods.

It looks like you only want to modify the behaviour of certain events in your `QWidget`. Lucky for you, there is already a mechanism in `QObject` to do just such a thing, it's called an Event Filter.

There is a nice example of how to use it in the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter), and a good advantage that improves on your class above is that you can use the same object to filter many `QWidget`s, instead of having one filter for each widget.